# tshark capture traffic - Channel Hopping

Tags: wifi, tcp, http, traffic, airmon-ng

I'm trying to capture the Wifi trafic from every AP. However when using `tshark -i wlan0mon -w capture -F pcap` and running a channel hopping script on the interface wlan0mon.

```
for ((  i = 1 ;  i <= 11;  i++  )) # channels range
do
iwconfig wlan0mon channel $i
tput cup 0 40          # row 0 and column 40 is used to show channel
echo -n "channel set to" $i " "      # put channel on screen
sleep 0.2 # stay on the channel for 1/10 seconds just like kismet
if [ $i -eq 11 ]
then
i=1
fi
done
```

I can't see any HTTP/TCP traffic when opening the written file on Wireshark.
I tried setting the interface `wlan0mon` channel with `airmon-ng start wlan0mon X` and I can now see the HTTP/TCP traffic.
Is it possible to capture HTTP/TCP traffic with channel hopping?